Extracting data in Excel inside Google Drive using App Script
I've been trying to extract data from Excel file stored in Google Drive. Here's what I've done so far:
function readExcelFromDrive(file_id='1_m2AR8UVOpn9XABPz_WvyPkLzz9OgyPs',debug=true) {  
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id);
  console.log(`File ${file_id} found.`)
  let blob = file.getBlob();
  let config = {
    title: "[Auto Generated Google Sheets] " + file.getName(),
    parents: [{id: file.getParents().next().getId()}],
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
  };
  let spreadsheet = DriveApp.createFile(blob).setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE,DriveApp.Permission.EDIT)
  console.log(`Temp spreadsheet created. Id: '${spreadsheet.getId()}'`)
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet.getId())
  console.log(`Temp spreadsheet opened.`)
  let data = ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
  console.log(data)
  }

I get the following error

how do i resolve this?
Thanks in advance

Is the error reproducible in a copy of this project?

Modification points:

In your showing script, spreadsheet is the XLSX file. Also, config is not used.
In your situation, it is required to convert the XLSX to Google Spreadsheet using Drive API.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
Before you use this script, please enable Drive API v3 at Advanced Google services.
function readExcelFromDrive((file_id='1_m2AR8UVOpn9XABPz_WvyPkLzz9OgyPs',debug=true) {
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id);
  console.log(`File ${file_id} found.`);
  let blob = file.getBlob();

  // --- I modified the below script.
  let config = {
    name: "[Auto Generated Google Sheets] " + file.getName(),
    parents: [file.getParents().next().getId()],
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
  };
  const { id } = Drive.Files.create(config, blob);
  let spreadsheet = DriveApp.getFileById(id).setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
  // ---

  console.log(`Temp spreadsheet created. Id: '${spreadsheet.getId()}'`);
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet.getId());
  console.log(`Temp spreadsheet opened.`);
  let data = ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  console.log(data);
}


When this script is run, the XLSX file is converted to Google Spreadsheet and the values are retrieved from the 1st sheet.
The created Spreadssheet is put into the same folder with the XLSX file.

Reference:

Method: files.create


What's the difference between DriveApp and Drive?
It worked like magic! Thanks @Tanaike. Sometimes i don't know when to use DriveApp and when to use Drive

@Cignitor Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About What's the difference between DriveApp and Drive?, DriveApp is Class object for managing files and folders with Google Apps Script. Ref

@Cignitor Drive is Class object for directly using Drive API. Drive API can be used with the HTTP request. Ref But, when Drive of Advanced Google services of Google Apps Script is used, Drive API can be easily used as Class object. There are also situations that DriveApp cannot achieve and Drive API can achieve. For example, it's your situation.

@Cignitor By the way, about It worked like magic! Thanks @Tanaike., When your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer
